# числа, введённые в разные строки, объединить в один список

Tags: python, строки, list

то есть, введены три числа a, b и с, и мне надо их закинуть в массив, чтобы получилось [a,b,c]

Answer (score 1):

Для решения вашей задачи существует множество способов.

Самым простым, пожалуй, будет ввод чисел по отдельности и последующее сохранение в массив:

```
a = input()
b = input()
... 

lst = [a, b, ...]
```

Но этот способ не назвать ни красивым ни эффективным. Можно воспользоваться циклом `for`:

```
num_of_inputs = 3 #кол-во вводов
lst = [] 
for _ in range(number_of_inputs):

    lst.append(input())
```

Но я бы сделал это через списковое выражение:

```
lst = [
    input() for _ in range(3)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Если честно, я не понял что вы хотите, но я так понял:

```
a = input("")
b = input("")
c = input("")
abc_list = [a,b,c]
print(abc_list)
```

Получает код работает так: программа запрашивает ввести три раза текст в переменные a, b, с, после ввода мы засовываем эти переменные в лист под названием abc_list потом вы его выводим с помощью print()

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```
res = []

for _ in range(3):
  number = input("Enter number: ")
  res.append(int(number))

print(res)
```